# Sails JS with Redis for caching

Tags: api, caching, redis, sails.js

As I said in my previous questions, I am trying to learn how to use sails.js, what I'm trying to do now is to cache the response of an api to redis. I have searched on how to do this, but I can't make it to work. Without caching, I call the api through ajax.

Any thoughts on how I will be able to do it using my controller? How can I call the api using the controller in sails.js and cache the response using redis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Steps:

#### Add to package.json

```
"redis": "^0.12.1"
```

#### Run

```
npm install
```

#### Create a service module  /api/services/CachedLookup.js

```
var redis = require("redis"),
  client = redis.createClient();

module.exports = {

  rcGet: function (key, cb) {
    client.get(key, function (err, value) {
      return cb(value);
    });
  },

  fetchApi1: function (cb) {
    var key = 'KEY'
    CachedLookup.rcGet(key, function (cachedValue) {
      if (cachedValue)
        return cb(cachedValue)
     else {//fetch the api and cache the result
        var request = require('request');
        request.post({
          url: URL,
          form: {}
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error) {
               //handle error
            }
            else {
            client.set(key, response);
            return cb(response)
            }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Inside the controller

```
CachedLookup.fetchApi1(function (apiResponse) {
      res.view({
        apiResponse: apiResponse
      });
    });
```

Comment: @Muntasim - I used this code in my sails Model:- 
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('redis connected');
});
client.set('framework', 'AngularJS');
console.log('Redis in action: ', client.get('framework'));  But I get error: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379. Do we need redis server running on our machine in addition to sails?  Can't we just use redis as a cache solution without its server?

Comment: Redis must be running :)